# Can't mass-assign protected attributes in Rails for non-existing model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Rails 3.2 and Ruby 1.9.3.

I know this has been asked again and again, but I can't find anything on my particular situation and even though it is surely something really silly, I can't figure it out.

My relations are like this: a product has many categories and a category has many attributes.

I want to create a nested form in my view, so I am using

```
= f.fields_for :categories do |category|
      = render 'category_fields', :f => category
```

in order to "attach" categories fields to the product form.

The problem is that, when it transforms it to HTML, the name of the category inputs are 'categories_attributes', as below:

```
<label for="product_categories_attributes_0_name">Name</label>
<input id="product_categories_attributes_0_name" type="text" size="30" name="product[categories_attributes][0][name]">
```

I am new to rails, but I guess it should be `product[categories][0][name]` instead of `categories_attributes`.

After I submit the form, I get

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: categories_attributes
```

Also, my models:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :product_type

  has_many :categories, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories

  attr_accessible :comments, :name, :price
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  has_many :attributes, :dependent => :destroy
  attr_accessible :name

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attributes
end

class Attribute < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category

  attr_accessible :name, :value
end
```

I am absolutely certain it is just a tiny error, but I can't spot it.

Help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add **categories_attributes** to your **attr_accessible** call in Product:

```
attr_accessible :categories_attributes, :comments, :name, :price
```

Add **attributes_attributes** to your **attr_accessible** call in Category:

```
attr_accessible :name, :attributes_attributes
```

**UPDATE:**

Three things happening here I am not to sure which one you can't tackle.

Using **accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories** in your Product model adds **categories_attributes=(attributes)** method to your model and allow you to save attributes on associated records through the parent(by passing them through *association*_attributes hash ).

It all happen because of how **params** hash is build when you are using fields_for helper in your form.

Simpler example:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories

  attr_accessible :categories_attributes, :name
end
```

If you are creating product through this form:

```
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
  Name: <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.fields_for :categories do |c| %>
    <%= c.text_field :name %>
    <%= c.text_field :desc %>
  <% end %>

 <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Your params hash will include:

```
{ :product => { :name => 'Tequila', :categories_attributes => { :name => 'essentials', :desc => 'i need more of it' } } }
```

or simplified:

```
{ :product => { :name => 'Tequila', :categories_attributes => { ... } } }
```

When in your controller you are creating Product:

```
@product = Product.new(params[:product])
```

Your re passing **:name => 'Tequila', :categories_attributes => { ... }** hash to Product.new. You are passing two parameters to it **:name** and **:categories_attributes**. Rails security requires you to white list all parameters that you pass to new, create methods with **attr_accessible** line. When you omit **:categories_attributes** rails will complain with:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: categories_attributes
```

Let me know if this clears everything.

More on [Nested Attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for)

More on [fields_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for)

More on [Mass assignment](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked like a charm. Your initial post was right, :attributes_attributes is necessary for Category as well.

Comment: But could you give me a simple explanation for this? I don't understand why this is happening.

Comment: Sure, you can do it whenever you want. :) Thank you very much.

Comment: That is a great answer, couldn't ask for more. Thank you very much!